# Assigning a C string to a ponter to characters - C++ program crashes

Tags: c++, arrays, string, crash

I know you can use the `string.h` class to solve this (I'm using C++), but I wish to learn why I'm getting a crash.

The error is minimal, it just crashes:

```
Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

I am trying to shift the string to the left by one so I can effectively erase the first character in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char * p1 = "192739@something.com";

    for (int i = 0; p1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        p1[i] = p1[i + 1];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What causes the crash?

Comment: string literal. stringer literals are unmodifiable. modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: If you're using C++, don't dual tag the question with C and C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p1` is pointing to a string literal, which is memory that you aren't allowed to modify. Declaring it as `char p1[] =` should fix your problem. Note that you can also treat `(p1 + 1)` as a string, as long as you know that there is at least one character in `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but this will work:

```
char *p1 = "192739@something.com";
char p2[100];

int i = 0;
char c = p1[0];
while(c != '\0')
{
    c = p1[i+1];
    p2[i] = p1[i+1];
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes catch a segmentation fault with C++ this way.  This code is only for learning, Catching signals that the operating system is programmed to listen and respond to can cause wacky head scratching behavior and would require a deep understanding of what operating systems are doing to your program under the hood.

**C++ code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void ouch(int sig){
    cout << "We get signal, main screen turn on. " << sig << endl;
    exit(0);
}
void setup(){
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = ouch;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, 0);
}

void this_method_causes_segmentation_fault_core_dump(){
    char * p1 = "192739@something.com";
    for (int i = 0; p1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        p1[i] = p1[i + 1];
    }
}
int main(){

    setup();
    this_method_causes_segmentation_fault_core_dump();

    return 0;
}
```

This code prints this for me:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘void this_method_causes_segmentation_fault_core_dump()’:
We get signal, main screen turn on. 11
```

This code is a hack, it uses processor and compiler specific undefined behavior and it comes with the usual warnings.  Depending on the KIND of segmentation fault you receive, this may not work.  However in many cases the program is able to run a few more commands (with possibly corrupted memory) before exiting.  Inside the ouch method, you might be able to get off a few more commands and gather information about the state of the program before the OS destroys it.

Basically this is the C++ program saying: "woah I  know I really messed up and the operating system hates me, but let me do just one more thing before the OS reclaims my resources".